# Como listar todas as categorias em menu wordpress automaticamente?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Estou tentando listar todas a categorias do wordpress para formar um dropdown menu com elas conforme o menu é criado no painel admin do tema.

Quero que onde esteja o item categorias no menu da imagem abaixo sejam listadas todas as categorias do site de forma automatica, mas com a possibilidade de o usuário poder escolher em que posição o item categoria ficara no menu.

Alguma forma de conseguir esse resultado?

**functions.php:**

```
function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'header-menu' => __( 'Header Menu' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

**header.php:**

```
<nav class="small-12 large-8 show-for-large cell">
    <?php $menu = str_replace('sub-menu', 'menu', wp_nav_menu( array(
        'echo' => false,
        'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
        'items_wrap' => '%3$s' 
    ))); 
    $categorias = get_categories(array(
        'orderby' => 'name',
        'order'   => 'ASC'
    ));
    ?>
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
        <?php  echo $menu; ?>

        <li><a href="#">Categorias</a>
            <ul class="menu">
            <?php foreach ($categorias as $categoria) {
                printf( '<a href="%1$s">%2$s</a><br />',
                    esc_url( get_category_link( $categoria->term_id ) ),
                    esc_html( $categoria->name )
                );
            }
        ?>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Imagem painel admin wordpress:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Para habilitar o submenu no wordpress após registrar o menu na functions, tu adiciona no array do `wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 1 ));`
Por padrão ele vem 0 
qualquer dúvida só ver a descrição de cada item do array aqui na [documentação wordpress](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)